# How to parse date and time into a universal timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

**Background:**

I'm working on a fit-bit fitness application.
So I get updates from the fit-bit API with date, time and the heart-rate at that point in the following format:

```
date = "2021-02-01"
time = "14:15:00" 
bpm: 78
```

Now, I need to convert this to a timestamp and save the heart-rate in the format =>(timestamp: heart-rate)
I query the heartrate data from the app based on the timetsamp - so they have to match.

**Problem:**
I am parsing the given data using moment.js to get the timestamp,

```js
let date = "2021-02-01"
let time = "14:15:00"
let t = moment(`${date} ${time}`, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss').valueOf();
console.log("Timestamp", t, new Date(t).toUTCString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For the above code, I am getting different values:

On my backend server where the database is updated :

```
"Timestamp",  1609510500000 Fri, 01 Jan 2021 14:15:00 GMT Fri,
```

As you can see it maps to Jan 1, please help

Comment: Are the date and time you receive in UTC? If so, you should be using `moment.utc(value, format)`. To get a `Date`, use `toDate()`, not `valueOf()` and `new Date()`. I'd also log it using `toISOString()`.

Comment: Also, your format string is incorrect. Month is `MM`, not `mm`, which is minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get different results on different systems is because a timestamp in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm (i.e. without a timezone offset) will be treated as local, so the host system's offset will be used when parsing it and hence generating a UTC time value from it. That means it represents a different moment in time in systems where the timezone offset is different.

If you want to send a UTC time value to the server, create a valid [ECMAScript timestamp](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) (a version of ISO 8601), parse it to a Date then get its time value, e.g.

```js
let date = "2021-02-01";
let time = "14:15:00";
let d = new Date(`${date}T${time}`); // Parse as local
let timeValue = d.getTime();
console.log(
  'Local: ' + d.toString() +
  '\nUTC  : ' + d.toISOString() +
  '\nTime value: ' + timeValue
);
```

It would also be useful to  see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

If you have UTC values to begin with, you can just call [*Date.UTC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) with appropriate year, month, day, etc. values to get the time value to use as a timestamp directly (remembering that months are zero indexed, so subtract 1 from the calendar month number, e.g. Jan = 0, Feb = 1, etc.).